# Pass info from text input through jquery in to php, which returns json, need to parse the return

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, json

I am getting a return of undefined. I don't even know what to do. So lost...

**html**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html>
        <head>
            <!--Jquery CDN-->
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

            <!--Local files attached-->
            <script type="text/javascript" src="CountryList.js"></script>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CountryList.css" />
        </head>

        <body>
            <div id="wrapper">
                <!--Header-->
                <h1>Country Information</h1>

                <!--input box-->
                <form>
                    <label for="countryInput">Input Country Name : </label>
                    <input type="text" id="countryInput"></input>
                </form>
                <br>
                <br>

                <!--Containing divs for lists-->
                <div id="wrapper2">

                    <!--countries will load here-->
                    <div id="countryList">
                        Countries:

                        <div id="actualList">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <!--country info will load here-->
                    <div id="countryInfo">
                        Country Info:

                        <div id="actualInfo">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
        <div id="footer">
            <!--Link to page-->
        </div>
    </html>
```

**css**

```
    body{
        margin-top:3%;
        background-color:white;
        text-align:center;
    }

    h1 {

    }

    h2 {
        font-size:14pt;
    }


    #header {
        color:white;
        text-align:center;
        padding:5px;
    }
    #footer {
        color:white;
        text-align:center;
        padding:5px;
    }

    #countryList {
        text-align:center;
        overflow:auto;
        width: 10%;
        height: 400px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        display: inline-block;
        float:left;
        margin-left:20%;
    }
    #countryInfo {
        text-align:center;
        overflow:auto;
        width: 49%;
        height: 400px;
        margin-right: 20%;
        border: 1px solid black;
        display: inline-block;
        float:right;
    }

    button {
        margin-left:15px;
        margin-top:10px;
        padding:5px;
        margin-bottom:10px;
    }
```

Javascript:

```
    $(document).ready( function(){
        var fieldInput = "";
        var countrylist = "";
        var countryinfo = "";
        var countryjson = "getCountryListAsJSON.php";
        $( "#countryInput" ).keyup(function( event ) {
            fieldInput = $(this).val();

            // show that something is loading
            $('#actualList').html("<b>Loading response...</b>");

            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: countryjson, 
                data: fieldInput,
                dataType: "json"
            })
            .success(function(data){
                alert("success");
                countrylist =data;
                console.log(countrylist[1]);
                $('#actualList').html(countrylist);
            })
            .done(function(data){


            })
            .fail(function() {

                // just in case posting your form failed
                $('#actualList').html("Failed to find countries.");

            });
        });
        $( "#countryInput" ).focus(function() {
            $("#countryInput").val("");
            $("#actualInfo").html("");
            $("#actualList").html("");
            fieldInput="";
        });
    });;
```

**the php script that was provided**

```
    <?php
        // Name:    getCountryListAsJSON.php
        // Desc:    Gets a sorted list of country names from the world DB which 
        //              begin with the specified letters
        // Params:  country - beginning string of letters to match
        // Outputs:   JSON encoded array of country names (strings)

        //get argument if provided
        if(isset($_GET['country']))
            $country = $_GET['country'];
        else
            $country = "no country specified!"; //will match nothing

        //connect to database
        $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "worlddemo", "worldpass", "world")
        or die("Some error occurred during connection " . mysqli_error($con));  

        //run query
        $query = "SELECT * FROM country WHERE Name LIKE '$country%' ORDER BY name"; 
        $results = mysqli_query($con, $query);

        //build an array of strings (country names) from results 
        $countryList = array();
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results))
        {
            $countryList[] = htmlentities($row['Name'], ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
            //note: special characters caused problems, hence htmlentities
        }

        //finish up
        mysqli_close($con);
        echo json_encode($countryList);
    ?>
```

I only get it returned as an undefined.
So I am trying to pass whatever is put in the text input to php.
For each key it is supposed to return a list of countries from a Database (hosted on my localhost xampp)
Im not sure whether its a problem with my teachers PHP or if I am just missing something in my code.  I have been trying to just get it to write out in the console to see if I am getting a proper return, but the only thing that seems to be happening is it is returning undefined.

link to the world db http://downloads.mysql.com/docs/world.sql.zip

Comment: Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools?  Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?

Comment: Also for debug purposes you could try to make an AJAX request to a static JSON file on the server which you fill with `{"demo":"data"}`.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I am running it on my schools webserver. We each get our own little spot on it. As for watching the ajax request, no error pops up in the console when inspecting it. [link](http://webdev.clackamas.edu/student/pruitt.jacob/asgn7/countrylist.html) Heres a link to the hosted page.  Though, for the purpose of the page, you would have to have the worlddb database file on your localhost.

Comment: Your teacher wrote some insecure PHP. Which return status do you fall into `success`?

Comment: @chris85 I get the alert saying that it worked. It returns undefined.  When I try to access the "getCountryListAsJSON.php" directly it seems like I dont have access to it on the server which is probably my main problem right now.

Comment: The AJAX request and a direct request should process the same, it is the same system user. If you load `getCountryListAsJSON.php?country=united`  what does it give you? Are you getting a 403 or what happens when you currently `dont get access`?

Comment: @chris85 Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1044): Access denied for user 'worlddemo'@'%' to database 'worlddb' in user\getCountryListAsJSON.php on line 16

Warning: mysqli_error() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given in user\getCountryListAsJSON.php on line 17
Some error occurred during connection

Comment: `mysqli_error` is the wrong function for connection errors, `die('Connect Error: ' . mysqli_connect_error());` - http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.connect-error.php Did you create the DB user and give it read rights?

Comment: @chris85 yeah the user exists and I even tried giving it all rights just to be safe.

Answer (score 0):

Access "getCountryListAsJSON.php" file directly from your browser (http://your-server/getCountryListAsJSON.php) and see what happens. If its all ok on the server side, you should see something like this on the page: ["country1", "country2", "country3", ... ]

Another thing you can try is change your success callback to something like this:

```
.success(function(data){
     //alert("success");
     var countrylist = data;
     var html = "";

     for( var i in countryList ){
          html += countryList[i];
     }
     $('#actualList').html(html);
 })
```

Comment: well, it seems like it isnt accessing the DB correctly...  so I guess thats my first place to start.

Comment: Got it to access the database, but it is only returning []   edit: NvM, back to not being able to connect.

Comment: Its just returning [] because the table country is empty or because your query is incorrect or the parameter $country passed to the query is not matching any register of the country table